# Html BeginForm does not trigger JavaScript code while pure HTML does

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have HTML code as below

```
    <form class="login-form" method="post">
       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" 
          name="username"/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
```

I have javascript logic

```
  $('.login-form').validate({

     ----
     ----
  });
```

When I click submit, javascript validation happens successfully. But now I tried to change HTML  to support MVC functionality in CSHTML file.

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("SignIn","Home", new {FormMethod.Post , 
          new { @class="login-form", role="form"}}))
      {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName, new {@type="text"})
            <button type="submit">
      }
```

But this is not triggering javascript validation during Html.BeginForm..

Answer (score 0):

You need an event listener
Try something like this:

```
$('.login-form').submit(function() {
            validate...
      });
```

You can also use a function and bind an onclick event to your button but above code more reader-friendly.